# How to integrate TinyMCE rich-text editor in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, text-editor, formik

I want to add tinymce rich text editor in my existing Formik form.

Previously:

```
          <Field name='description'>
              {({ field, meta }) => (
                <div>
                   <textarea
                    id='article_body'
                    type='text'
                    rows='15'                  
                    placeholder='Write description...'
                    {...field}
                   ></textarea> 
                 </div>
            </Field>
```

Now:

```
      <Field name='description'>
         {({ field, meta }) => (
           <div>
            <Editor
                id='article_body'
                apiKey='my-api-key'
                initialValue='Write...'
                init={{
                  height: 500,
                  menubar: true,
                  plugins: [
                    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                    'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount',
                  ],
                  toolbar:
                    'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor |  alignleft aligncenter 
                     alignright alignjustify |  bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat |help',
                }}
                onEditorChange={(content, editor) => {
                  console.log(content);
                }}
                textareaName='description'
                onChange={field.onChange}
                onBlur={field.onBlur}
                value={values.description}
              />
          </div>
       </Field>
```

It's not working, It's not found field values I think, that's why it shows an error 'Description required!'

Answer (score 9):

The Formik handleChange is expecting an object with a 'target' property that has both 'name' and 'value' properties. The TinyMCE onEditorChange is only passing in the new value. The following works for me:

```
onEditorChange={(e) => {
    handleChange({ target: { name: 'description', value: e } })
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use `setFieldValue`

```
 onEditorChange={(stringifiedHtmlValue) => {
     formik.setFieldValue("youFieldName", stringifiedHtmlValue);
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, @preston that worked for me. Attaching the screenshot for a better understanding of how it is working.

[image]